# Passing data between a series of related functions

Tags: python, function, arguments, chaining

I am attempting to create an exam grading program. I successfully wrote each function to do what I need it to, but when I attempt to execute the entire program, I am running into issues with my return variables not being referenced.

Here is my code for context:

```
def userinput():
    allinputs = []
    while True:
        try:
            results = list(map(int, input('Exam points and exercises completed: ').split(' ')))
            allinputs.append(results)
        except:
            ValueError
            break
    return allinputs

def points(allinputs):
    exampoints = []
    exercises = []
    exercises_converted = []
    gradepoints = []
    counter = 0
    for i in allinputs:
        exampoints.append(i[0])
        exercises.append(i[1])
    for e in exercises:
        exercises_converted.append(e//10)
    for p in exampoints:
        p2 = exercises_converted[counter]
        gradepoints.append(p + p2)
        counter += 1
    return (gradepoints, exampoints, exercises_converted)

def average(gradepoints):
    avg_float = sum(gradepoints) / len(gradepoints)
    points_avg = round(avg_float, 1)
    return points_avg

def pass_percentage(exercises_converted, exampoints):
    failexam = []
    passexam = []
    passorfail = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(exampoints):
        if exampoints[i] < 10 or exercises_converted[i] + exampoints[i] < 15:
            failexam.append("fail")
            passorfail.append(0)
        else:
            passexam.append("pass")
            passorfail.append(1)
        i += 1
    percentage_float = len(passexam)/len(failexam)
    percentage = round(percentage_float, 1)
    return (percentage, passorfail)

def grades_distribution(passorfail, gradepoints):
    grades = []
    i = 0
    l = 5
    while i < len(gradepoints):
        if passorfail[i] == 0:
            grades.append(0)
        elif passorfail[i] != 0 and gradepoints[i] >= 15 and gradepoints[i] <= 17:
            grades.append(1)
        elif passorfail[i] != 0 and gradepoints[i] >= 18 and gradepoints[i] <= 20:
            grades.append(2)
        elif passorfail[i] != 0 and gradepoints[i] >= 21 and gradepoints[i] <= 23:
            grades.append(3)
        elif passorfail[i] != 0 and gradepoints[i] >= 24 and gradepoints[i] <= 27:
            grades.append(4)
        elif passorfail[i] != 0 and gradepoints[i] >= 28 and gradepoints[i] <= 30:
            grades.append(5)
        i += 1
    while l >= 0:
        print(l, ": ", "*" * grades.count(l))
    return


userinput()
print("Statistics:")
points(allinputs)
print(f"Points average: {average(gradepoints)}")
print(f"Pass percentage: {pass_percentage(exercises_converted, exampoints)}")
print("Grade distribution")
grades_distribution(passorfail, gradepoints)
```

I have no problems with the mechanics *within* each function; rather, my error lies where I try calling each of them from the main function.

The `user input()` function runs fine, and returns `allinputs`. However, when the second function `points(allinputs)` is called, the program states that the argument is undefined.

Comment: You made a mistake in `userinput`. `ValueError` needs to be part of the except statement (`except ValueError:`); it has no effect if you just put it on a new line by itself.

Comment: Also, regarding "the program states that the argument is undefined", please edit your question to show the whole error message, starting from `Traceback`.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the return value of a function before passing it as argument.
This should solve your problem

```
allinputs = userinput()
points(allinputs)
```